# Casting None to snowflake table in a TIMESTAMP_NZT column giving expression type error

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowpark and pandas to add a dataframe to snowflake table.
My table looks like

```
ID column2 .......... Timestamp_column
                             None
                             2023-09-25 20:16:59.6670000 +00:00
```

The timestamp column is of type TIMESTAMP_NZT(9) in the snowflake table (it is nullable). My dataframe can have either a date of format 2023-09-25 20:16:59.6670000 +00:00 or NONE in it.

Now when I am trying to write an MERGE query to merge the pandas df to snowflake table I get the following error

```
SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01af524e-0201-df06-0000-f6b5005ea472: 002023 (22000): 01af524e-0201-df06-0000-f6b5005ea472: SQL compilation error:
Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_TZ(9) but got NUMBER(38,0) for column Timestamp_column
```

My code is as follows

```
df['Timestamp_column'] = df['Timestamp_column'].replace({"None": None})

temp_df = snowpark_sess.write_pandas(
        df=df,
        table_name="df",
        overwrite=True,
        auto_create_table=True,
        table_type="temp",
        quote_identifiers=False,
    )
upsert_df = snowflake_table_df.merge(source=temp_df,join_expr=(snowflake_table_df['ID']==temp_df['id']),
 clauses=[when_matched().update({"ID":temp_df["id"],
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                                 "TIMESTAMP_COLUMN":temp_df["timestamp_column"]}),
         when_not_matched().insert({"ID":temp_df["id"],
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                                 "TIMESTAMP_COLUMN":temp_df["timestamp_column"]})])
```

But when ran I get the error Expression type does not match.
How can I cast `None` to a column with datatype TIMESTAMP_NZT(9) in snowflake table.

When I run a INSERT INTO query in snowflake table with timestamp_column as `NULL` it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Python `None` is not the same as Snowflake `NULL`.

You can cast your Python None to NULL before sending it to Snowflake and then it would work.
Here is an example when I just use a value on the variable:

```
my_var = 123455

my_df = session.sql(f"SELECT {'NULL' if my_var is None else my_var}::TIMESTAMP_NTZ").show()
```

I get:

```
---------------------------
|"123455::TIMESTAMP_NTZ"  |
---------------------------
|1970-01-02 10:17:35      |
---------------------------
```

and when I use None for the variable:

```
my_var = None

my_df = session.sql(f"SELECT {'NULL' if my_var is None else my_var}::TIMESTAMP_NTZ").show()
```

I get:

```
-------------------------
|"NULL::TIMESTAMP_NTZ"  |
-------------------------
|NULL                   |
-------------------------
```